# Running python3 -m venv project return exit status 1

Tags: python-3.6, ubuntu-16.04, python-venv

According to the [venv documentation in **Python3**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html):

> Changed in version 3.5: The use of venv is now recommended for creating virtual environments.

With *Python3.6* installed in my *Ubuntu 16*, I tried to create a Python project with command `python3 -m venv project`, but got the following error:

`Error: Command '['/home/me/git/project/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

*Question*: Why could this have happened? and how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install -y python3-pip` is worth a try, based on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-programming-environment-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-server

If that fails, what does `python3 --version` print?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I indeed have python3-pip installed. But still got the same error